# Maya Python error: keyword can't be an expression?

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I'm creating a user interface in Maya using Python. I keep getting this error:

```
Error: line 1: keyword can't be an expression
```

Does anybody know how to counter this?

[image]

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
if mc.window(ram, exists =True):
    mc.deleteUI(ram)

ram = cmds.window("RenamerWin",t = "Renamer Tool", w=300, h=300)
cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
cmds.text("Welcome to the tool renamer")
cmds.separator(h=10)

cubW = cmds.intSliderGrp(1 = "Width",min =0, max =10, field =True)
cubH = cmds.intSliderGrp(1 = "Height",min =0, max =10, field =True)
cubD = cmds.intSliderGrp(1 = "Depth",min =0, max =10, field =True)

cmds.button(l = "Create a Cube",c="myCube()")

cmds.showWindow(ram)

def myCube():
    myCubeWidth = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubW , q= True,value =True)
    myCubeHeight = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubH , q= True,value =True) 
    myCubeDepth = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubWD , q= True,value =True)
    finalCube = cmds.polyCube(w=myCubeWidth,h=myCubeHeight,d=myCubeDepth , n = "myCube")
```

Comment: Always post code as text here directly from the start. Pictures of code are significantly less helpful.

Comment: @Carcigenicate just updated it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. You're using `mc` and `cmds` interchangeably.  This might work if you'd done both at different times in your listener but it won't work as written
2. `ram` is not defined in before you use it.  Line 2 will fail for anybody who hasn't run this before.
3. You typed the number 1 when you wanted the letter L.
4. You mistyped the name of the last slider in `myCube()`
5. Button commands need to take an argument.

Here's a working version; check the differences with what you had. Note that I put the whole thing inside a def to make sure it doesn't get you in trouble with the leftovers of earlier runs:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def example ():
    ram = 'RenamerWin'
    if cmds.window(ram, q = True, exists =True):
        cmds.deleteUI(ram)

    ram = cmds.window("RenamerWin",t = "Renamer Tool", w=300, h=300)
    cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
    cmds.text("Welcome to the tool renamer")
    cmds.separator(h=10)

    cubW = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Width", min =0, max = 10, field = True)
    cubH = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Height", min =0, max = 10, field = True)
    cubD = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Depth", min =0, max = 10, field = True)

    def myCube(_):
        myCubeWidth = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubW , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeHeight = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubH , q= True,value =True) 
        myCubeDepth = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubD , q= True,value =True)
        finalCube = cmds.polyCube(w=myCubeWidth,h=myCubeHeight,d=myCubeDepth , n = "myCube")

    cmds.button(l = "Create a Cube",c=myCube)

    cmds.showWindow(ram)

example()
```

Comment: how would you then allow the user to input location information for the y z x axis?
cheers

Comment: Same basic thing... you'll have to add the controls before you declare `myCube`, and access them the same way it's done there.  You can just use the `xform` command on the newly created cube to move it to the specified location